# Javascript how to get the ID of selected Item

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I'm using Web2Py to send a list of values to my view.

My HTML is like this:

```
<select id="DestinationOptions" onchange="SetDest(this)">
    {{for key, value in dirList.iteritems():}} 
        <option name="DirListItem{{=key}}" id="{{=key}}"> {{=value}}</option>
    {{pass}}
</select>
```

My javascript is like this:

```
function SetDest(destComboBxID)
{
    alert(destComboBxID.id);
    var e = document.getElementById(destComboBxID);
    var path = e.option[e.selectedIndex].value;
    alert(path);
    //document.cookie = "GD_"+file.id + "=" + file.id + ";";
}
```

I only get the to the first `alert()` and then I get the following error when i debug in the brower:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'options' of null`

Q: How can I get the ID of the selcted value?

Comment: note: your `template` is like this, not `HTML`

Comment: replace `var e = document.getElementById(destComboBxID);` with `var e = destComboBxID;`

Comment: if it's not HTML, what would you call it? It is from a *.html file...

Comment: it is called template, which is processed by template engine to render html, file name extension is not so important, but in this case *.html is wrong

Answer (score 5):

You could add an EventListener to the select field. When it changes, you can get the ID of the selected option by using `e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('id')`.

```js
document.getElementById('DestinationOptions').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    console.log(e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].getAttribute('id'));
});
```

```html
<select id="DestinationOptions">
    <option id="1">Hello</option>
    <option id="2">World</option>
</select>
```

Comment: how to get id='DestinationOptions'  ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="DestinationOptions" ="SetDest(this.id)">
```

Comment: So I think if the code use (this)keyword only it will return object refer to that select not it is ID then inside the function he use it as ID so I think the solution is to use (this.id).